# is there concept about multiplecpu in mxnet

Tags: mxnet

As we know, there is concept about multiplegpu in mxnet,when specify -gpu in command.And if we don't specify gpu,it will run it on cpu.How many cpus do it run ?Can it possible to specify multiple cpu?

Answer (score 1):

You can use several CPUs with the following code (R version, in python is pretty similar):

```
devices = lapply(1:2, function(i) {
    mx.cpu(i)
})
```

And the train the network as usual. Also if you have [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl/) library the system automatically computes with all cores.

Answer (score 0):

A couple ways to look at this.

If you compile MXNet with a good BLAS library, those math operations will use all the CPU cores available.

Also, you can specify how many CPU worker threads through the environment variable `MXNET_CPU_WORKER_NTHREADS`.  See http://mxnet.io/how_to/env_var.html

Comment: How to set MXNET_CPU_WORKER_NTHREADS in R